# Regex matching over its boundaries

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to take a body tag with regex and then replace with something append to it. Problem is that by using the following regex it fails because it selects everything pass the limits  my  regex should hold on.

**regex**: `/<body.*[^>]>/i`

**test** string: `<bla bla ><body class='a b ... what ever..d'><fo bar>`

**Target**: `<body class='a b ... what ever..d'>`

**example**: http://jsfiddle.net/bogdanm/qbccq79z/

**Problem**: 
instead of matching `<body class='a b ... d'>` it selects `<body class='a b ... what ever..d'><fo bar>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` is a greedy quantifier and works well with negated classes. The problem you are having is with using the quantifier with `.` that makes the regex engine match ("read") all up to the end looking for a character other than `>` and then `>`. The regex engine finds this combination at the final `r>`. So, you get the wrong match.

You need to set the `*` quantifier to `[^>]` negated character class and remove `.*` that is matching all up to the end:

```
var testStr= "<bla bla ><body class='a b c d'><fo bar>";
var reg = /<body[^>]*>/i;

var match = reg.exec(testStr);

if(match != null){
  // we know  regex matched
  alert(match[0].toString() + '\n');
}
```

Here is the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9pLmx3jj/)

Comment: The quantifier is `*` perhaps you meant character or character class?

Comment: To be clear i understand the wrong part of my regex: (please corect me) 
select <body  to > as long the > is not contained. This could be a sintactical interpretation?

Comment: @vihan1086: I might be using wrong wording, all I meant was using the `*` quantifier after `[^>]` character class.

Comment: @BogdanM.: Adding the explanation to the answer.